# Modular Arithmetic Question (Rosen Discrete Mathematics and its applications)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I came across this exercise in *Rosen Discrete Mathematics and its applications* and even after spending an hour plus googling I couldn't find an answer that could explain how this question is to be done. I saw somewhere that a certain theorem is used, but I'm not sure how it is applied.

$(19^3\mod23)^2\mod31$

**The answer is:**
$((-4)^3 \mod 23)^2\mod31=(-64\mod23)^2\mod31=25$

**Possibly useful theorem**:

If $a \equiv b\mod m, c\equiv d\mod m$ then $ac=bd(\mod m)$

**My question:** I'm concerned with how I can get from $19^3$ to $(-4)^3$.

Thank you!

Comment: Because $-4\equiv19\mod 23$ (because $23|23=19-(-4)$

Comment: $19$ and $19 \pm 23k$ leave the same remainder when divided by $23$

Comment: Also, $19^a$ and $(19\pm 23k)^a$ leave the same remainder when divided by $23$.

Comment: The composed mod operators look fishy. What is the exact statement of the problem?  You may be misunderstanding relational vs operational mod.

Comment: @BillDubuque the exact statement is "33. Find each of these values." and exactly as what I have written above

Comment: What is the exercise / page number?

Comment: Page 245, 4.2 Integer Representations and Algorithms, Qn 33c

Comment: Thank you for all your comments, both answers were helpful but I had to pick the one that directly answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because $19 \equiv -4 \pmod{23}$ (or equivalently $23|(19-(-4))$), hence $19^3 \equiv (-4)^3 \pmod{23}$

Answer (score 1):

You apply the given [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242). When we iterate it on the same congruence  (i.e. by induction) we obtain the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\  \bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{a\equiv b\,\Rightarrow\, a^n\equiv b^n}\, $ for all $\,n\in\Bbb N.\,$ Therefore

$$\bmod 23 \!:\,\ 19\equiv -4\,\Rightarrow\, 19^3\equiv (-4)^3$$